# Running python multiprocessing keeps dropping number of processes, why?

Tags: python, linux, parallel-processing, processors

I submitted multiple jobs on Linux machine using python parallel processor using: (imported pool from multiprocessing)

```
parallel = Pool(processes = 10)
```

I had about 4000 jobs .. it was utilizing all the processors for first few days but it started dropping the number of processes. Currently I have around 300 jobs left and it is down to 4 processes used. It is not using full 10 processors

My guess is python initially assigned the jobs to all processors before hand and some processors completed their job early and are now sitting idle.

Is this correct assumption ? Is there any way around this so all processors are utilized till end to finish the runs faster ?

`def run_parallel(self, my_jobs):
        #give the number of processors
        parallel = Pool(processes = 10)
        #run jobs in parallel
        parallel.map(run_jobs, my_jobs)
        return`

Comment: Hard to say anything without actual code, if you could add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, it would help a lot. Or at least some more context. Oh, and welcome to Stackoveflow!

Comment: Thank you for your response and welcome. Here is the method I am using : 

def run_parallel(self, my_jobs):

        #give the number of processors

        parallel = Pool(processes = 10)
        
        #run my_jobs in parallel

        parallel.map(self.run_jobs, my_jobs)


        return

Here self.run_jobs is a list of different jobs with input from my_jobs runs (4000 of them). When I ran this initially it did all 10 of them .. now with 300 jobs left it is only using 3 processors 

Hope this clears it a bit.

Comment: @sanubhatta Please, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40162638/edit) the question and add the code from comment there. It is difficult to read it directly from the comment.

Comment: Added the code to main question. Sorry still new to stackflow :-)

Comment: I can think of at least one reason, some of your processes die. If a process encounters exceptions, it will terminate. Therefore, if will be helpful that 1. you examine what errors your process encounters and 2. make use of try ... except ... finally to keep the process running.

Comment: This is usually due to a bug in the child worker - so logging and try/except are good ideas. `Pool` has a `maxtasksperchild` parameter that will cause the child processes to be terminated and restarted periodically. The theory is that if the worker is bleeding objects for some reason, this is a brute force cleanup operation. For instance, suppose the child isn't closing file handles and eventually they run out. You can set it to `1` to always cleanup - that's reasonable if the processing itself is long an expensive - or some random value you just guess.

Comment: `Pool.map` has a `chunksize` parameter. Normally, `map` will divide the jobs evenly and submit large chunks to the child processes at a single time. This reduces the handshaking needed when child workers want more jobs. However, suppose jobs take a variable amount of time and some processes end up with more long jobs than short jobs. Eventually, the processes with a speedy list will stop leaving the unlucky ones slaving away. For jobs with significant processing overhead, `chunksize=1` should be used.

Comment: Thank you guys. You are all very helpful.